# Use of illustrations of tv shows etc. in my tshirts

Tags: print-design, screen-printing

I have started a t-shirt company. Can i use illustrations of tv shows and movies freely on my t-shirts?

Comment: This is a mine-field. You will be involved with copyright law, which varies across countries. You may be able to get away with "Parody" use but your question is rather too vague as it is to form a decent answer.

Comment: We aren't lawyers here.  This is a question for your lawyer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, But in a very high percentage of cases you will need the permission of the IP/Copyright holder.

For example, you could easily make Star Wars logo branded t-shirts but you will definitely need the express written permission of Disney (who will also charge you royalties)

One slight back-door can be "Parody" eg a storm-trooper riding a unicorn across a rainbow coming out of Yoda's mouth.

This is also highly territory dependent.

You probably should have looked into this before starting a company.

TLDR: - Ask a copyright lawyer.